# How to write the dataframe/matrix into CSV using R but with commas in values

Tags: r, csv

I simply want to export my matrix into a csv file but some columns contain comma in their values. I also tried to replace the commas with other symbols, such as "|".but it still does not work.

For example my text looks like this

```
"41305348","PLAZA HOTEL(CHAMPAGNE BAR,ROSE CLUB, PALM COURT, EMPLOYEE CAFETERIA)","1","768","5 AVENUE","10019","2127593000","03","2012-10-25 00:00:00","U","10F","27","B","2012-10-25 00:00:00","2013-02-15 01:01:09.020000000"
"41305395","DUMPLING HOUSE","1","118 A","ELDRIDGE STREET","10002","2126258008","20","2013-01-10 00:00:00","D","10F","13","A","2013-01-10 00:00:00","2013-02-15 01:01:09.020000000"

webextract.raw=readLines(mytext)
webextract.split2=sapply(webextract.raw,function(x)strsplit(x,"[^[:alpha:]],[^ ]"))
t=sapply(c(1:14),function(x)sapply(webextract.split2,function(y)y[x]))
write.table(t,"t.csv")
```

If I use `write.table` directly, the first record will be separated into more columns than the second one as there are commas in `"PLAZA HOTEL(CHAMPAGNE BAR,ROSE CLUB, PALM COURT, EMPLOYEE CAFETERIA)"`.

Any thoughts on how to escape this and wrap `"PLAZA HOTEL(CHAMPAGNE BAR,ROSE CLUB, PALM COURT, EMPLOYEE CAFETERIA)"` together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the qMethod and quote parameters to [write.csv](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/write.table):

```
write.csv(my.text, stdout(), qmethod='escape', quote=TRUE)
```